# getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, pinia

i get this error: Uncaught Error: []: getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
const pinia = createPinia()
app.use(pinia)
This will fail in production.
at useStore (pinia.mjs:1691:19)
at PokemonDetails.vue:3:22

what's wrong with my code?

**pokemonDetails:**

```
<script>
import { usePokemonStore } from '../stores/PokemonStore';
const pokemonStore = usePokemonStore();
export default {
  name: 'PokemonDetails',
  methods: {
    evolutions() {
      return [
        pokemonStore.evolutionOne,
        pokemonStore.evolutionTwo,
        pokemonStore.evolutionThree,
      ];
    },
    resetApp() {
      this.$router.push('/');
      pokemonStore.$reset();
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <template v-if="pokemonStore.findPokemon == false">
    <div class="firstDiv">
      <div class="secondDiv">
        <div>
          <strong>{{ pokemonStore.pokemonName }}</strong
          ><img :src="pokemonStore.selfie" alt="foto de pokemon" />
          <p>Elemento Principal: {{ pokemonStore.type }}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <strong>Habilidades:</strong>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="stat in pokemonStore.stats[0]">
              {{ stat.stat.name }}: +{{ stat.base_stat }}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divEvolutions">
        <strong>Evolução</strong>
        <ul class="evolutions">
          <li v-for="evolution in evolutions">
            <img :src="evolution.selfie" />
            {{ evolution.name }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button v-on:click="resetApp" class="newSearch">Nova pesquisa</button>
    </div>
  </template>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.firstDiv {
  text-align: center;
}
.secondDiv {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  max-height: 600px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  background-color: $gray-200;
  div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
.divEvolutions {
  background-color: $gray-200;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.evolutions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
.newSearch {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: $gray-200;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  &:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: $gray-200;
  }
}
</style>
```

**pokemonStore.js:**

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const usePokemonStore = defineStore('pokemon', {
  state: () => ({
    findPokemon: true,
    pokemonName: '',
    speciesLink: '',
    selfie: '',
    type: '',
    stats: [],
    evolutionOne: {},
    evolutionTwo: {},
    evolutionThree: {},
  }),
  getters: {},
  actions: {
    addPokemon(
      name,
      species,
      selfie,
      type,
      stats,
      evolutionOne,
      evolutionTwo,
      evolutionThree
    ) {
      this.pokemonName = name;
      this.speciesLink = species;
      this.selfie = selfie;
      this.type = type;
      this.stats.push(stats);
      this.findPokemon = false;
      this.evolutionOne = evolutionOne;
      this.evolutionTwo = evolutionTwo;
      this.evolutionThree = evolutionThree;
    },
  },
});
```

**main.js:**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';

import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

import './assets/main.css';

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(createPinia());
app.use(router);

app.mount('#app');
```

i tried call my store in computed:

```
  computed: {
    pokemonStore() {
      return usePokemonStore();
    },
    evolutions() {
      return [
        this.pokemonStore.evolutionOne,
        this.pokemonStore.evolutionTwo,
        this.pokemonStore.evolutionThree,
      ];
    },
  },
```

it works, but i believe is don't the best practices

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stores aren't supposed to be used before Pinia is installed to Vue application.

The reason why `use...` composables are created by Pinia `defineStore` instead of store objects is that this allows to avoid race conditions.

Here `usePokemonStore` is called on `pokemonDetails` import before Pinia install. `pokemonStore` is referred in the template while it's not a part of component instance. For a component with options API it should be:

```
  name: 'PokemonDetails',
  data() {
    return { pokemonStore: usePokemonStore() }
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

I went through this in a recent episode and this happens when you try to access the pinia without having created it before.

I defined a file called global.ts that contains the instructions below

```
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
export const piniaInstance = createPinia()
```

Then in my user store.ts file I imported the pinia instance already created globally and included it in the store, thus directly exporting the store to any location requested.

```
import { UsuarioData } from "@/recursos/classes/Usuario";
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { piniaInstance } from '@/recursos/global'
import { userStorageKey } from '@/recursos/constantes'

const usuarioStore = defineStore('usuario', {
  state() {
    return {
      dadosUsuario: new UsuarioData()
    }
  },
  actions: {
    deslogar() {
      localStorage.removeItem(userStorageKey)
      this.dadosUsuario = new UsuarioData()
      console.log('usuario após deslogar', this.dadosUsuario)
    },
    logar(dadosUsuario: UsuarioData) {
      localStorage.setItem(userStorageKey, dadosUsuario.Token)
      this.dadosUsuario = dadosUsuario
    }

  },
  getters: {
    obterUsuario() : UsuarioData {
      return this.dadosUsuario
    },
    obterTokenAcesso() : string {
      return this.dadosUsuario.Token
    }
  }
})(piniaInstance); // pinia instance

export default usuarioStore
```

this worked for me. Even if I have several stores, I can call the pinia instance within the stores and pass it as a parameter

remember to import the pinia instance into your main.ts/js file as well

```
import '@/assets/styles/app.css'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { piniaInstance } from '@/recursos/global'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './recursos/router'


const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router).use(piniaInstance)
app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you aren't mixing options and composition API components up and copy/pasting without thinking.  Using pinia on an old options API component is different.

Answer (score 0):

In project terminal:

1. npm uninstall -g @pinia
2. npm list -g @pinia

you will get this error
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "@pinia" of package "@pinia": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/spark/.npm/_logs/2023-07-15T07_29_36_570Z-debug-0.log

3. npm uninstall @pinia
4. npm cache clean --force
5. rm -rf node_modules
6. npm install @pinia

this will fix

if you get this error
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "@pinia" of package "@pinia": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/spark/.npm/_logs/2023-07-15T07_30_56_791Z-debug-0.log

add this again
rm -rf node_modules,
npm cache clean --force,
npm install

this will change the project pinia version if you are collabing change it with what is best to not get into other issue when hosting.

Answer (score 0):

**just a quick update for Vue JS 3:**

if you are using VueJS 3 then you have to wrap the useStore in the setup function like this:

```
export default {
setup(){
const pokemonStore = usePokemonStore();
return {
pokemonStore
}
}
```

Note: I am using given versions of vuejs and pinia:

```
 "vue": "^3.3.11",
 "pinia": "^2.1.7",
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be add  tag.
Composition API is essential

Comment: <script> => script setup

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).