# "getActivePinia() was called but there was no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?" error in console, but the app compiles successfully

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

I'm trying to follow along a Pinia tutorial and got stuck on this error: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?

I'm building a simple todo app in order to understand how Pinia works. I'm using Vue 3.2.13 and Pinia 2.1.4. I followed the steps described in the official Pinia documentation, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my main.js file:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import App from './App.vue';

const app = createApp(App);
const pinia = createPinia();
app.use(pinia);

app.mount('#app');
```

This is my App.vue file:

```
<template>
    <main>
        <input />
        <button>Add</button>
        <div v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">
            <strong>{{ todo.text }}</strong>
            <button>Toggle</button>
        </div>
    </main>
</template>

<script>
    import { useTodosStore } from '@/store/todos';
    const { todos } = useTodosStore();
    export default {
        name: 'App',
        data() {
            return {
                todos
            };
        },
    };
</script>
```

And this is my store file, todos.js:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useTodosStore = defineStore('todos', {
    state: () => ({
        todos: [
            {
                id: 1,
                text: 'Clean room',
                isFinished: false,
            },
        ],
    }),
});
```

I was expecting to see it work, but I get a blank page instead and this error message in the console:
[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ba8N.png)

Also, the app compiles without any issues:
[Compilation report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sFW4.png)

I tried to apply what I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75497775/getactivepinia-was-called-with-no-active-pinia-vue), to no success.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useTodosStore` is a composable, a feature of Vue 3's Composition API, but your App.vue is written using Options API (Vue 2 API).

Composables and Options API are incompatible.

If you're not familiar with Composition API, consult the Vue 3 [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#script-setup) and familiarize yourself with the syntax.  Your App.vue written with Composition API could be written like so:

```js
<script setup>
import { useTodosStore } from '@/store/todos';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

const store = useTodosStore();
const { todos } = storeToRefs(store)
</script>
```

It is recommended to use Pinia with Composition API but [Options API is supported](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#usage-with-the-options-api) with the use of helpers like `mapState` if you strongly prefer sticking with the older API

```js
<script>
import { mapState } from 'pinia'
import { useTodosStore } from '@/store/todos';

export default {
  computed: {
    // read-only state
    ...mapState(useTodosStore, ['todos'])
    // writable state
    //...mapWritableState(useTodosStore, ['todos']),
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. I wasn't aware of the Composition API, I'm new to Vue as well :)